# Groups inside structs

Tags: data-structures, system-verilog

Can I have groups inside a struct?

pseudo-code:

```
typedef struct {
     input_group {
             logic a;
     }
     output_group {
             logic b;
     }
} my_signals_list
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no.

If you want to have signals grouped like this, why not create a struct for the input group and a struct for your output group?

```
typedef struct {
  logic a;
} input_group_s;

typedef struct {
  logic b;
} output_group_s;

typedef struct {
  input_group_s input_group;
  output_group_s output_group;
} my_signals_list;
```

As Greg points out in the comments, you can also have nested struct definitions inside the main struct:

```
typedef struct {
  struct { logic a; } input_group;
  struct { logic b; } output_group;
} my_signals_list;
```

If you want to specify signals for a module in a nice encapsulated fashion, I would suggest using an `interface`, though.

Comment: I was thinking about the AXI specification: the signals are grouped instead of input/output seperate logic.

Comment: FYI: Nested structs are allowed: `typedef struct { struct { logic a; } input_group; struct { logic b; } output_group; } my_signals_list;`

Comment: @user2692669 You can have an individual interface for each AXI channel and then have those as members/ports of a bigger AXI interface. It seems a bit overkill, though, since you're probably always going to be connecting full interfaces, not just individual channels.

Comment: @Tudor can you update your answer with Greg's comment so it gets accepted?