# Modport trouble using complex struct

Tags: system-verilog, hdl

From my previous question ([Groups inside structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275803/groups-inside-structs/26277400#26277400)), after creating typedef structs, I tried to form an interface from 5 different channel signal declarations (the structs).

The struct's form is:

```
typedef struct  {

    struct {
        logic  [1:0]  a;
        logic  [2:0]  b;
    } in;

    struct {
        logic  [4:0]  d;
    } out;

} axi_X_ch;
```

Then I tried the following code:

```
interface axi_interface ();

    //as = axi slave
    axi_X_ch as_X;
    axi_Y_ch as_Y; //similar to struct axi_X_ch

  modport slave ( input  as_X.in,  as_Y.in,
                  output as_X.out, as_Y.out);

endinterface
```

But I get the `error` message (ignore the coordinates):

```
modport slave ( input  as_X.in,  as_Y.in, output as_X.out, as_Y.out);
                           |
ncvlog: *E,ILLHIN (demo.sv,177|30): illegal location for a hierarchical name (as_X).

modport slave ( input  as_X.in,  as_Y.in, output as_X.out, as_Y.out);
                                     |
ncvlog: *E,ILLHIN (demo.sv,177|30): illegal location for a hierarchical name (as_Y).
...  (same for the next two output declarations) ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modport items should be variables inside the interface not just part of them. Moreover, you are referencing your modport items as types, not variables:

```
modport slave ( input  axi_X_ch.in,  axi_Y_ch.in, output axi_X_ch.out, axi_Y_ch.out);
```

`axi_X_ch` is a type, not a variable.

What you want to achieve can be done by something called "[modport expressions](http://www.asic-world.com/systemverilog/interface4.html)" (not sure if all synthesis tools support it).

So, using modport expressions, you can create new port names called `X_IN, Y_IN, X_OUT, Y_OUT`:

```
modport slave ( input  .X_IN(as_X.in),  .Y_IN(as_Y.in), 
                 output X_OUT(as_X.out), output .Y_OUT(as_Y.out));
```

**EDIT:**

If modport expressions are not supported, the closest thing I can think of is:

```
typedef struct {
        logic  [1:0]  a;
        logic  [2:0]  b;
    } t_in;

typedef struct {
        logic  [4:0]  d;
    } t_out;

interface axi_interface ();
    t_in as_X_in;
    t_out as_X_out;
    t_in as_Y_in;
    t_out as_Y_out;

  modport slave ( input  as_X_in,  as_Y_in,
                  output as_X_out, as_Y_out);
endinfterface
```

This loses part of the grouping that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: sorry there was a typo in my example (I used `as_X` not `axi_X_ch` ). I tried the solution and I got `ncvlog: *E,MODPXE (test.sv,177|30): Unsupported modport expression for port identifier 'X_IN'.`. If I can't solve this with these structs, is there another way to reconstruct my AXI channels so I put together a nice and neat Interface?

Comment: Wow, with axi that means 10 groups... Overkill?

Comment: You can put them in an array

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow: put what in an array? (each channel has different signals).

Comment: I was thinking of an array of `t_in` and `t_out`. For example: `t_m [4:0] INS` and `t_m [4:0] OUTS`

Comment: I think this would get even more complicated. I've decided to just split the signals just to inputs and outputs and seperate them with newlines and placing comment titles between them.